# Example code locked on android studio, and padlock icon doesn't change it

Tags: android-studio, arcore

I have downloaded the example code of ARCore (HelloSceneform) and i want to edit the BaseArFragment.java file, but when i type nothing happends.
(i want to change a gesture from tap to doubleTap)
I've tried pressing the padlock icon on the bottom-right corner but the file is still locked.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not in android studio, you are trying to change file from sceneform sdk. You should rather try to extend ArFragment in your code and implement necessary changes there.